# python regex: capture different strings line by line from .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to extract names/strings from [a .txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b9CniQ_vXF7j28UHAQ5vNxLaQYvOf015/view?usp=sharing) line by line. I am trying to use regex to do this.

Eg. In this below line I want to extract the name "Victor Lau", "Siti Zuan" and the string "TELEGRAPHIC TRANSFER" in three different lists then output them into an excel file. You may see [the txt file also](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b9CniQ_vXF7j28UHAQ5vNxLaQYvOf015/view?usp=sharing)

TELEGRAPHIC TRANSFER        0008563668 040122          BRH  BDVI0093   VICTOR LAU                                           10,126.75-                .00             10,126.75-  SITI ZUZAN 16:15:09

I have tried this code

```
for file in os.listdir(directory):
     filename = os.fsdecode(file)
     if (filename.endswith(".txt") or filename.endswith(".TXT")) and (filename.find('AllBanks')!=-1):
        with open(file) as AllBanks:
            for line in AllBanks:
                try:
                    match4 = re.search(r'( [a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+ )|( [a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+)', line)                    
                    List4.append(match4.group(0).strip())                     
                except:
                    List4.append('NA')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([List4,List5,List6]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df.to_excel('AllBanks.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Please include all relevant information as _part of your question_. Links to external files are not allowed

Comment: Pranav ji - the link is to my own file. A sample file which will help in looking at the data.
If links are not allowed then what is the function of the link icon in posts?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Pls edit wherever you feel like. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text file looks to be fixed width columns - no delimiters.
You can use re capture groups like '^(.{20})(.{15})(.{30})'

or you can specify the columns start position and width and use that to splice out the data from each row.

This method will parse 2 columns from each line of your file and return an array of rows, each with an array of columns.

```
def parse(filename):
    fixed_columns = [[0, 28], [71, 50]] # start pos and width pairs of columns you want
    rows = []
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            cols = []
            for start,wid in fixed_columns:
                cols.append(line[start: start+wid].strip())
            rows.append(cols)
    return rows

for row in parse(filename):
    print(", ".join(row))
```

Output:

```
TELEGRAPHIC TRANSFER, LIEW WAI KEEN
TELEGRAPHIC TRANSFER, KWAN SANG@KWAN CHEE SANG
TELEGRAPHIC TRANSFER, VICTOR LAU
TELEGRAPHIC TRANSFER, VICTOR LAU
```

From here you can save the data any way you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I am not sure what was the issue with Mr. Pranav for downvoting my question. It is so usual stuff in stackoverflow.